# Using a database for a Node.js application that runs in the terminal

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, nosql

I'm currently writing a program that is a To-Do list that just runs locally on my machine in the terminal screen(written in node.js, no extra dependencies). I've set up everything and it works totally fine, but I have never actually used any databases other than just session cookies on the browser. What would you all suggest I use when all I want to do is learn how to store some simple data in a database and then be able to manipulate it in the same fashion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated on this one! I'm really just looking for suggestions on a good database, as well as a bit of guidance on the best way to use that particular technology. I'm familiar with SQL and NoSQL databases, but like I said, I have never even used one on an actual application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, You can use mongodb which is easy to configure and manipulate data. It helps you to work on json objects directly from database. Use express to create your RESTful endpoints and exposed data. Sometime back i use it for angular application, repo link is below for your reference :

[AngularJs, ExpressJs, MongoDB application](https://github.com/abhilive/meanapp)

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlite` which provides a good SQL API but keeps things very simple by simply using a file on your disk and accessing it through code directly in your application. You don't need to start another server and take care of configuring it.

For a simple To-Do list that should be more than adequate for storing your data whilst keeping your configuration simple and easy.

Here's a tutorial on how to set it up:
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/

You'll essentially be using the sqlite3 npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3

That page also comes with brief usage instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs has client libraries for database interaction
Ex.
For SQL database:
postgresql : https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres
For NoSQL db:
mongodb : https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose

You can also create pool of db connections